# Best way to call one javascript file from another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a JavaScript newb but am familiar with the procedural/dynamic workings of Ruby. What is the simplest way to start executing code from a different JavaScript file? All I know how to do is execute code from one file.

Comment: You're looking for `require()`.

Comment: yes i think so, but does require just load the code but not execute the code from the other file?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for node's module system (there are frameworks that provide this for front-end as well.) Stack Overflow questions should be concerning a specific issue and including the relevant code. I suggest deleting this question as it will be closed.

Comment: express and other frameworks seem to do the require() stuff implicitly am i right?

Comment: @AlexMills What you mean by `execute` is quite unclear. You get access to the code from another file, then make calls to it or use it however you wish.

Comment: are there any other ways besides require()? this question is legit. coming from java, the scripting language world is way different in a f'ed up way

Comment: @AlexMills Different doesn't necessarily mean f'ed up.  Different for sure though.  For what it's worth, JavaScript is flexible enough that you can structure your applications however you want.  You could easily recreate the structure of Enterprise FizzBuzz if you wanted.  https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition  I wouldn't though.  And remember, there are plenty of languages that compile to JavaScript these days.  Perhaps you'd appreciate something like TypeScript.  http://www.typescriptlang.org/  Or, JSIL:  http://jsil.org/

Comment: There is no concept of "loading" code in Javascript.

Comment: You need to read http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node.js uses what is called the [Common.JS module pattern](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1).  A module exports an object, which is loaded by whatever required the module.

For instance, suppose I have a file called SomeClass.js:

```
exports = function SomeClass () {
  this.func = function () {
    console.log('func!');
  }
}
```

Now in my main app.js:

```
var SomeClass = require('./SomeClass.js');
var someClass = new SomeClass();
someClass.func(); // outputs "func!" to console
```

You can read more about this in the official docs:  http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: yes, thanks. perhaps I need to include some nodeJS libraries to get the "require()" to work. Right now, I have two .js files in the same directory, and "var x = require('otherJSfile.js');" causes an error. The error being "cannot find module x.js"...I will figure this out, but still not always straightforward is it

Comment: VERY strangely, as I am on a Windows machine....this worked "var xz = require('./xz.js');" .... "./" is usually a solution on a unix machine...oh well...it works

Comment: @AlexMills Sorry, I have updated the example to include `./`.  Yes, this is needed for Node.js apps regardless of platform.  I think the docs said otherwise, but I've always needed it.  I also use Windows for Node.js development, and test on both Windows and Ubuntu.